# AWK Linux shell variable calling a shell variable

Tags: function, shell, variables, awk

this is probably an easy/what-the-hell-is-that question: here a blueprint of the script where I load 4 variables $1 $2 $3 and $4 in a function 'myloop'
say

```
file1   
1 2 3  
1 4 5  
1 6 7
```

```
myloop () {
 echo col=$1 $2 $3 $4
 awk -v c1="$1" -v c2="$2" -F, 'BEGIN {
        FS=" ";
 }
 {
        xy+=($c1*$c2);
 }
 END {
        print "Product" $3 "and " $4  #this is where $3 (='h2') and $4 (='02') don't print
        print "prod= " xy;
 }' file1 > res.txt
}
myloop 2 3 h2 o2
```

expected output in res.txt

```
product h2 and 02  
prod = 68
```

so as I said in the commented line in the code, I can't get to read $3 and $4.
I try passing $3 and $4 with
`awk -v c1="$1" -v c2="$2" -vl1="$3" -v l2="$4"  ...` and then call $l1 and $l2 in the print statement but that does not work.
any hint would be appreciated as I'm no expert (as you can tell) in scripting
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide concise, testable sample input and expected output. I was trying to guess at what you might want your code to do but that's just silly when you could simply show us.

Comment: Inside the END block of the `awk` program, `$3` is the 3rd column of the last line.  it is completely unrelated to the 3rd argument of the function.

Comment: @WilliamPursell inside the END block the value of $3 is undefined by POSIX so it'll be different things in different awks. It'll be the value of $3 from the last read line in some awks, it'll be null in others, and it could be anything else the provider chooses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

myloop() {
    echo "col=$*"
    awk -v c1="$1" -v c2="$2" -v l1="$3" -v l2="$4" '
        {
            xy += $c1 * $c2
        }
        END {
            print "Product", l1, "and", l2
            print "prod =", xy+0
        }
    ' file1
}

myloop 2 3 h2 o2

$ ./tst.sh
col=2 3 h2 o2
Product h2 and o2
prod = 68
```

`l1` and `l2` are bad choices for variable names though since `l` looks far too much like `1` in many fonts and so obfuscates your code.

By the way, in your code in your question, this:

```
awk -F,
```

is changing FS from it's default value of a blank to a comma and then this:

```
BEGIN {
        FS=" ";
 }
```

is setting it back to the default blank value it had to begin with. Just don't do that.

Comment: this works very well and does the job indeed. Code and comment are now dully noted - many thanks for the dig out!!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called string interpolation and can be performed like so:

```bash
print "Product  ${3} and  ${4}"
```

Comment: No. You're thinking of shell syntax, not awk.

Comment: I got Product ${3} and ${4}
prod= 1.0495

Comment: If you are using awk, then use `printf "Product %s and %s", $3, $4;`

Comment: No, that's also wrong. The value of $3 and $4 in an END section is undefined but it's extremely unlikely it'd be the 3rd and 4th arguments to the calling shell function as the OP seems to want printed.

Comment: @EdMorton: I see what you mean i think - I tried to fix it by 'declaring' $3 and $4 in the awk -v, but no luck

Comment: Again - edit your question to provide a [mcve] then we can help you. We can't definitively tell what you want to do by reading code that doesn't do what you want to do.

Comment: dummy example and expected output added now